# How Can I Reduce "Splashiness" in the Kitchen Faucet?

Tags: faucet

I'm renting a home and the kitchen faucet causes a lot of splashing.  The first thing I did was un-screw the little piece on the end to check the aerator, and there wasn't one.  So I went to the hardware store and bought what I *thought* was right, just a little aerator screen to insert into the un-screwed piece.

But that didn't seem to make a difference.  The stream coming out of the faucet doesn't seem very aerated (still looks pretty laminar) and it still splashes a lot.

Is there something else I can try?  Every faucet I've ever used has been pretty well aerated, so I'm not really sure what to do here.

Comment: You should probably buy a new aerator.  There are a few pieces to it.  Bring the whole piece in to the hardware store and get one that matches the faucet threads.

Comment: @Edwin: There are more pieces?  I thought it was just a little screen, about the size of a penny.  Perhaps I am indeed missing something in the overall assembly...

Comment: There's an exploded view of an aerator on this page. http://www.rooter2.com/cleaning-a-faucet-aerator/ The other important part besides the screen is the plastic mixer. The rest just hold and seal everything together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screen is just one part of an aerator.  There are a few different components to an aerator. It's best to get a new aerator instead of trying to track down all the individual pieces.  It'll be worth the little bit of extra money. To make sure you get the right aerator the first time, I recommend that you bring the old one into the hardware store to match the threads.